# dplyr split by semi colon in case_when

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have a dataframe `df`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1:10), Type = c('a', 'a;b','b','a','b','b','c','a;c','b;c','c'))
```

And I want to add a column called `color`, based on the values that appear in `Type`. (This is just an example, in my code there are many more variations of `Type`, i.e. `d;f`, `e;q`,`a;z` etc)

```
df %>% 
  mutate(color = case_when(
    Type == 'a' ~ 'red',
    Type == 'b' ~ 'blue',
    Type == 'c' ~ 'green',
    TRUE        ~ as.character(Type)
  ))
```

As this stands, it returns

```
   ID Type color
1   1    a   red
2   2  a;b   a;b
3   3    b  blue
4   4    a   red
5   5    b  blue
6   6    b  blue
7   7    c green
8   8  a;c   a;c
9   9  b;c   b;c
10 10    c green
```

I am curious if there a way to split by semi-colon within the `case_when()`, in order to produce the output

```
   ID Type color
1   1    a   red
2   2  a;b   red;blue
3   3    b  blue
4   4    a   red
5   5    b  blue
6   6    b  blue
7   7    c green
8   8  a;c red;green
9   9  b;c blue;green
10 10    c green
```

Comment: The simplest solution is to add those instances (i.e., TYPE == "a;b"....)

Comment: You just add more conditions to you case_when call and it should be done.

Comment: @roarkz This is just an example..in reality I have too many to code for each individually

Comment: You could use seperate to split by the semicolon and then mutate_at on the two TYPE columns and then recombine the columns.

Comment: @roarkz Can you submit that as an answer with code so I can see / accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split the *Type* column into separate rows, map it to colors and then paste them together:

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr);
df %>% 
    separate_rows(Type) %>% 
    mutate(color = case_when(
        Type == 'a' ~ 'red',
        Type == 'b' ~ 'blue',
        Type == 'c' ~ 'green',
        TRUE        ~ as.character(Type)
   )) %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   summarise_all(funs(paste0(., collapse=";")))

# A tibble: 10 x 3
#      ID  Type      color
#   <int> <chr>      <chr>
# 1     1     a        red
# 2     2   a;b   red;blue
# 3     3     b       blue
# 4     4     a        red
# 5     5     b       blue
# 6     6     b       blue
# 7     7     c      green
# 8     8   a;c  red;green
# 9     9   b;c blue;green
#10    10     c      green
```

---

Besides `case_when`, you can also put the character to color maps in a vector and then retrieve the colors later:

```
map <- c(a = 'red', b = 'blue', c = 'green')
df %>% 
    separate_rows(Type) %>% 
    mutate(color = map[Type]) %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    summarise_all(funs(paste0(., collapse=";")))
```

Comment: to the rescue once again! Although I don't think the semi-colons in the `library()`s are necessary.

Comment: They are not necessary if not trying to put them in a single line.

Comment: Just tried your second approach with my own example, and it's giving error on `summarise_all`. I have integers instead of characters for the `map` vector. I.e., 3310 instead of a, 50156 instead of b, etc.

Comment: Try add this in the `mutate`, `coalesce(map[Type], Type)` so if the specific item doesn't have a color, it will be the `Type` itself instead of `NA`. And also if you have integers, you can create the `map` as `map <- c('3310' = 'red', '50156' = 'blue')` for instance.

Comment: Still giving same error: `Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: no applicable method for 'collapse' applied to an object of class "character".`

Comment: Did you omit the function `paste0`? Notice the function applied is `paste0(., collapse=';')`, `collapse` is a parameter to `paste0` function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152282/discussion-between-kyle-weise-and-psidom).